# Setup iis load balancer for https

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, load-balancing, iis-8.5

I have made my local machine as load balancer. I have other two machines as applications servers which I have provided in my server farm. I need to set up https

I took help of https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing.

But no luck with https.

Following is the url rewrite settings.

[image: URL Rewrite Settings]

When I make request, I receive 404 after accepting the certificate in browser.

Share appropriate steps for https site load balancing in IIS.